# jQuery don't reset if hasClass

Tags: jquery, class, reset

I have a form where on button submit the correct answers have a class of correct. Currently when I reset the form all right and wrong answers are reset. Is there a way using jQuery where only the answers with a class of incorrect will reset but the answers with the class of correct will remain displayed.

Something along the lines of

```
$(".e02.c02.p01e #activity #reset_activity:not(.correct)").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$("#activity_contents").html($activity);
refreshActivity(342);
});
```

Except that does not work

Thanks

More info.

This is a jQueryUI sortable activity. The reset button currently resets all the sorted items. I only want the reset to move the incorrect items back to the original position.

Comment: Can you add more code - I think I understand what you are asking, and yes, that should be easily done. When you say `reset`, are you clearing an input? radio buttons?

Comment: the `:not` selector should work fine. I suspect there are more pieces to the puzzle than indicated in your question. Check out this [simplified jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x00jxxv6/) demo which shows how `:not` can be used

Comment: Thanks I can see that method working. I will try and get this working and come back to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help. I rephrased my question in another post as I did not explain it very well. The solution is at:

[Excluding div with class from .html()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35330904/excluding-div-with-class-from-html#35330958)